# PHP Illuminate syntax errors

Tags: php, slim

I'm working on an API implementation that was developed using Slim. It uses Illuminate for DB operations.  I've pulled the code and have a local environment set up, but when I try to make a request that involves a database operation I get a PHP error - unexpected '.'

Look at one of the class files, I see the following:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return static::connection()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

The original developer isn't available to ask and I'm puzzled as to what the `...` is doing in front of the variable name and how to resolve the errors that I'm getting - can anyone help?

The same code is on the staging and prod environments and works fine there.

Thanks

Comment: `...` is operator unpacking - http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Comment: If the error your getting is a syntax error, check the version of PHP as ... was introduced in 5.6

Comment: Thanks for that. PHP version is 5.4.x - so that's obviously the issue.